# JAVA: How to access another object's subclass?

Tags: java

I have an instance of the object VMemRead (let's call it r).  The constructor for VMemRead looks like

```
VMemRead(SourcePos sourcePos, VVarRef dest, VMemRef source)
```

with fields `dest` and `source`.  I know when I want to access dest, I can just do `r.dest`.  However, I want to go "deeper" into source.

VMRef has two nested classes `VMemRef.Global` and `VMemRef.Stack`.  VMemRef.Global has the constructor

```
VMemRef.Global(SourcePos sourcePos, VAddr<VDataSegment> base, int byteOffset)
```

I want to access the `int byteOffset`.  In effect, I want to do something like `r.source.Global.byteOffset` but Java doesn't let me do this.

Is there any way I can access that value?

Documentation:
VMemRead: http://cs.ucla.edu/classes/spring11/cs132/kannan/vapor-parser/vapor-parser-javadoc/cs132/vapor/ast/VMemRead.html#source

VMemRef: http://cs.ucla.edu/classes/spring11/cs132/kannan/vapor-parser/vapor-parser-javadoc/cs132/vapor/ast/VMemRef.html

VMemRef.Global: http://cs.ucla.edu/classes/spring11/cs132/kannan/vapor-parser/vapor-parser-javadoc/cs132/vapor/ast/VMemRef.Global.html

Thank you very much!

Comment: format your question, and format it good, don't just slap random code blocks around words

Comment: How so?  I thought I marked the code as code appropriately.

Comment: Also I am confused by what you mean nested? Inner class or you literally extend it by saying `extends VMemRef`...? Because saying `r.source.Global.byteOffset` is definitely wrong no matter which way it is. Just don't know which you exactly you have it.

Comment: @pauliwago  Make it look less like an ugly pile of text.  Use less run-on sentences.  Just read it to yourself.  You'll find that it's very hard to follow

Comment: Literally extend VMemRef....but it's in the same class file/surrounded by brackets of VMemRef..if that makes sense.  Please let me know if you need more clarification.

Comment: Yes, the nested classes are static.  VMemRead does NOT have fields of type Global and/or Stack.  Those are the names of the subclasses.

Comment: @SamIam I hope that's pretty enough for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Those nested classes are static. For each of them, you need a reference to an instance in order to access the field values. An instance of `VMemRef` does not have (documented) member fields of type `VMemRef.Global` or `VMemRef.Stack`. You'll have to look somewhere else than in `r` for data from those classes.</strike>

In other words, simply because you have an instance of `VMemRef` in `r`, it doesn't mean that there are any instances of `VMemRef.Global` or `VMemRef.Stack` around. So there's no way to access "those values" because "those values" don't necessarily exist!

**EDIT** After re-reading the API, I see that `VMemRef` is an abstract class and `r.source` is an instance of either `VMemRef.Global` or `VMemRef.Static`. That changes the story. You can do something like this:

```
if (r.source instanceof VMemRef.Global) {
    VMemRef.Global source = (VMemRef.Global) r.source;
    // access fields specific to VMemRef.Global
} else if (r.source instanceof VMemRef.Stack) {
    VMemRef.Stack source = (VMemRef.Stack) r.source;
    // access fields specific to VMemRef.Stack
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!  That actually makes a lot of sense, but what is being printed out then when I print out `r.source.toString()` then?

Comment: @pauliwago - Ah. It looks like you never have an instance of `VMemRef`; it's always an instance of `VMemRef.Global` or `VMemRef.Stack`. I updated my answer to show how to deal with that.